# How to find the content of a sphone

Tags: tag-removed

I need to know how to find the contents of a sphone; however I have not been able to find an equation for it online. I noted that the equation for a cone is 1/3(h)(A base). So I thought that perhaps the formula for a sphone could be the volume of its base * h * 1/3 since a sphone is a continuous series of spheres terminating to a point similar to the continuous circles terminating to a point in a cone.

Comment: Can you be more precise what a sphone is? It seems to be unknown to Google.

Comment: Also, please indicate more clearly why this is a research level mathematics problem, or move the question to math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks Carlo! So... this was my first question, what qualifies as a research level mathematics problem? I didn't realize that there was a place called math.stackexchange.com. How do I move this there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sphone](http://hi.gher.space/wiki/Sphone) is a 4-dimensional generalization of a cone (height $h$), where the base is a sphere (radius $r$). It is one of a collection of 4-dimensional objects, see [this overview.](https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/explain/round.htm#top) The surface equation is
$$|(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^{1/2}+(r/h)x_4|+(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^{1/2}=r,$$
the volume is $\frac{1}{3}\pi r^3 h$.

Comment: Wait, that website says that the surcell volume is 4/3 * pi * r^3 * h

Comment: the 4D bulk volume is $\frac{1}{3}\pi r^3h$, the 3D surcell volume is $\frac{4}{3}\pi( r^3 +r^2\sqrt{r^2+h^2})$.